# Uploading to pypi, and downloading with pip

Tags: python, package, pip, distutils, pypi

I've written a small tool and uploaded to to pypi ([here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=undo&version=0.5.1&%3aaction=display)), but I can't download it using pip.  Here is the pip log:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
c:\python32\scripts\pip-script.py run on 04/11/12 15:53:45
Downloading/unpacking undo

  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/undo
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/undo: HTTP Error 301: Moved Permanently - Redirection to url '/simple/undo/' is not allowed
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/undo when looking for download links for undo
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Real name of requirement undo is undo

  URLs to search for versions for undo:
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/undo/
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/undo/
  Getting page http://bitbucket.org/aquavitae/undo
  Analyzing links from page http://pypi.python.org/simple/undo/
    Skipping link http://bitbucket.org/aquavitae/undo (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/undo/); not a file
    Could not parse version from link: https://bitbucket.org/aquavitae/undo/get/latest.tar.gz (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/undo/)
    Skipping link https://bitbucket.org/aquavitae/undo/get/latest.tar.gz (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/undo/); wrong project name (not undo)
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement undo

No distributions at all found for undo

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 104, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\python32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 245, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\python32\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 978, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "C:\python32\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 157, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for undo
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?  I am behind a proxy, and I though that this might be the problem but pip has no issue with other packages, just this, so I assume I've somehow packaged it wrong.

Comment: Could https link would be skipped by pip? Did you try with http link instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether its a bug in pip or deliberate, but once I opened up the bitbucket site it worked, despite the fact that the actual file it needed to download (and did download) is hosted on pypi.  So if anyone else has this problem, the solution is to make sure that all links on the pypi page are accessible, even if they don't host the download file.

Answer (score 1):

The link to bitbucket in https works only when you are authenticated. Use http link on bitbucket instead.

*(Same issue for both website / issue tracked links in the pypi page, i can't access to it without login first)*

**Edit**: http link redirect to the login page, and after login, i got:

> You do not have access to this repository.

Comment: The https link that pip is picking up isn't even on pypi - it was a while ago, but I removed it when I realised that it was https, and in the wrong name format.  Pip should just download the tar.gz file on pypi.  It appears I made the bitbucket repo private, so I'll correct that when I'm next at my computer, but it shouldn't affect downloading from pypi.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems: your tar file has not got the package name in it ( 'undo' not a substring of 'latest.tar.gz'); and pypi for some reason wanted to redirect (which does not seem to be normal, so I will not go into that).

Normally pip first looks at all the urls that match your package name, both on the home page and on the download pages pypi provides on http://pypi.python.org/simple/undo/ (assuming you specified both). Any url on those pages that has the project name in it is somewhere is analysed.

Several things make pip reject a url:

```
Skipping link http://bitbucket.org/aquavitae/undo (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/undo/); not a file
```

This url has undo in it but it is not pointing to a file.

```
Could not parse version from link: https://bitbucket.org/aquavitae/undo/get/latest.tar.gz (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/undo/)
```

There is no version number in `latest.tar.gz`

```
Skipping link https://bitbucket.org/aquavitae/undo/get/latest.tar.gz (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/undo/); wrong project name (not undo)
```

no project name `undo` in the file component.

That things now work is because `https://bitbucket.org/aquavitae/undo/downloads` is accessible and has 3 links with undo in the filename part in it and many, many links that don't. Use:

```
pip install undo --no-install --log undo.log
```

and look at the `undo.log` file.

Please note that pip uses the function parse_versions from the pkg_resources (in dist_packages) to determine what is the newest version available. So even if you specify `undo-1.1.tar.gz` explicitly as the the version on your pypi download link, if your homepage also points to newer version like `undo-1.2-dev-20120614` the latter is taken as found.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a link ending in something like latest.tar.gz#egg=undo

Answer (score 0):

Change `setup.py`'s `download_url` to https://bitbucket.org/aquavitae/undo/get/undo-0.5.1.tar.gz.